# How can i update hidden field value on one page from the code behind of another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page, behaviorAnalysis.aspx, that is calling a javascript that does two things: 1) Display a modal dialog with a please wait message; and 2) creating an iFrame and calling a second page, behaviorAnalysisDownload.aspx via jQuery:

```
function isMultiPageExport(exportMedia) {
    waitingDialog.show("Building File<br/>...this could take a minute", { dialogSize: "sm", progressType: "warning" });

    var downloadFrame = document.createElement("IFRAME");

    if (downloadFrame != null) {
        downloadFrame.setAttribute("src", 'behaviorExport.aspx?exportType=html&exportMedia=' + exportMedia);
        downloadFrame.style.width = "0px";
        downloadFrame.style.height = "0px";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadFrame);
    }
}
```

The second page is downloading an Excel file using the following code snippet:

```
//*****************************************
//* Workbook Download & Cleanup
//*****************************************
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
wb.Write(stream);
stream.Dispose();

var xlsBytes = stream.ToArray();
string filename = "Behavior Stats YTD.xlsx";

MemoryStream newStream = new MemoryStream(xlsBytes);

if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
{
    HiddenField exp = (HiddenField)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("hidDownloadStatus");
    exp.Value = "Complete";
}

HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(xlsBytes);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

As you can see, I was hoping to update a hidden field on the calling page before pushing the download through; however, PreviousPage is null. Is there another approach I can use, to update the hidden field value from the calling page, behaviorAnalysis.aspx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first recommend this jQuery library, which does exactly what you want with the background download and modal, but it's been tested cross-browser and has a lot of neato features already available: http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

If you don't like that, you can take a similar approach to what that plugin does. Instead of trying to set the value of a HiddenField on the parent, just add a cookie:

```
Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("fileDownload", "true") { Path = "/" });
```

After your first page appends the iFrame, just use setInterval() to check to see if that cookie exists with something like:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('fileDownload') > -1) {
    document.cookie = 'fileDownload=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;' // remove cookie
    // it was a success, so do something here
}
```

Of course, you'll want to put some sort of a timeout or logic to handle errors, but that should cover the basics of it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! I took a look at John Culviner's plugin, and if I hadn't have already done so much I would have definitely used it.  It looks like I had the same thoughts as he did -- I was just missing that final piece -- creating a cookie and checking for it's existence.  So I just followed your suggestion of creating the cookie, and it's working perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you have to offer the file on the cliend side by creating an Iframe? May you can call directly your server side method on the same page.

Another possibility would be to subscripe the iframe onload event and setting there the hidden value (client side).

```
'<iframe src="....." onload="downloadComplete()"></iframe>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Making the call directly on the server method kills the session thread. After you change the Response.ContentType to download, once it executes the download it thinks it's work is done and effectively ends the session -- no commands are carried out after Response.End.

Comment: I did like your thought about using the iFrame "onload" method, but that did not work either -- I'm guessing for the same reasons, the session thread stops immediately and does not even report that it's finished.  I did find an answer below though...

Answer (score 0):

In second Page add this:-

`<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath ="~/PreviousPage.aspx" %>`

Then try and let me know if this works.

Comment: @JimmyGenslinger if this doesn't work use LinkButton instead of iframe like this `<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" PostBackUrl="~/behaviorExport.aspx?exportType=html&exportMedia=test" runat="server">Test</asp:LinkButton>`

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! I was really optimistic about adding the PreviousPageType, but it did not work...I'm wondering if it's because the code behind is performed first, so it hasn't read/added this yet?  Next I tried switching to a linkbutton as you suggested, but this did not work either.  I kind of rushed through that and am wondering if I did not set up something properly, because I've read in other places that that should have worked.  I did, however, resolve my problem...below...